# Update to a specific version of PHPUnit

Tags: php, phpunit

Currently my system installed phpunit is on 4.3.1

Doing phpunit --self-update will update to the latest version of phpunit which is 5.3.* at the moment.

I like to update it to a specific version (4.8.24)

How am I suppose to do this?

Note: I know about the composer option, but I would like to do it on my system installed phpunit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up changing the phpunit.phar file on my `/usr/local/share/phpunit/` folder

This dev environment is set up via this http://vccw.cc/ and it installs phpunit 4.3.1, I need 4.8.24 coz I'm doing wordpress plugin unit testing http://wp-cli.org/docs/plugin-unit-tests/ it says there 4.8.* is required.

So here is what I did.

1. Download latest 4.8.* version of phpunit here https://phpunit.de/
2. Rename the phar file to phpunit.phar ( I remove the version section )
3. Execute this `chmod +x phpunit.phar` to make the phar file executable
4. Copy the phpunit.phar to `/usr/local/share/phpunit/` folder

Note: I remove the old phpunit.phar ( that is the 4.3.1 ) and replace with this new one

Also their is already a symbolic link on `/usr/local/bin/phpunit` for `/usr/local/share/phpunit/phpunit.phar` setup by vccw.

I think changing phpunit version can be done too via modifying the provisioning files provided by vccw but I'm not that in to provisioning scripts, only basic knowledge.

I hope this helps other devs, specially windows devs like me working on unix based dev env.

PS. This dev env is only used by me, it isn't version controlled so its ok for me if I make changes to the dev env directly ( not via provisioning scripts provided by vccw )